# How to place an animated checklist button right to text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a template form I found which gives me a neat checklist form that I can use for a website I'm trying to develop (I'm doing this to learn)
So I want to know how to make these buttons:

[image]

appear on the right side of the text (I want to use RTL language)

To make it easier, here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h1jokddo/

I tried to modify the css code, adding "margin: right" to some of the properties but no luck:

```
    body {
  background: #069ffb;
  color: #fff;
}

.ac-custom {
  padding: 0 3em;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0 0 80px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom label::before {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
  content: '';
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  color: #fff;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  left: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
  stroke: #fdfcd3;
  stroke-width: 13px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: none;
}


/* Box Fill */

.ac-boxfill svg path {
  stroke-width: 8px;
}
```

I need to know what to change there.
As I stated before, this is something I'm doing in order to learn, this is how I learn at least, I take something that is already working, and try to find out what makes everything work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `padding` from your label and add the desired amount of pixels to `left` of your checkbox in the css. Also add the amount of pixels to the left of the `svg`
Like so:

```
.ac-custom label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom label::before {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  left: 55px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwhvf1xf/1/)

Comment: see the update, missed that the first time, I updated link and fiddle

Comment: That's good, but the first element text on the list is not highlighted when selected

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code at the end of your css

```
.ac-custom label {
  padding: 0;
}
.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"], .ac-custom label::before {
    left: 40px;
}
.ac-custom svg {    
    top: 54%;
    left: 49px;
}
```

Updated : https://jsfiddle.net/arifahmedjoy/h1jokddo/7/

Comment: This is great, but for some reason in my code, the text goes on top of the box and everything is indented to the left

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer : Show me in fiddle or an url to check

Comment: Don't share image. It won't help me to debug. Give me real time example.

Comment: You have to achieve this using jQuery. Set the value of 'left' in checkbox dynamically based on the label width, you can use .width() jQuery function for that.

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example at the fiddle? Thanks.